# updating class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In the following html, jquery, bootstrap code,

```
addMenuBar : function addNavigation (component) {
    var html = '<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">';
    html += '<li id ="scenario" class="disabled"><a href="#">Scenario</a></li>';
    html += '<li id ="resolutions" class="disabled"><a href="#">Resolutions</a></li>';
    html += '<li id ="triggers" class="disabled"><a href="#">Triggers</a></li>';
    html += '</ul>';
    component.append(html);
    $('ul[id="scenario"] li').addClass("active");
}
```

where the component is a container div as follows:

```
    this.container = $(document.createElement('div'));
    this.container.addClass('patient-hover-inner');
    this.container.appendTo(this.form);
```

I want to change the class for the 'li' item for id = 'scenario' from 'disabled' to 'active'. how do i do this? The above won't work without any errors

Comment: `$(document.createElement('div'))` You are using jQuery: `$("<div>")`

Comment: Firstly you're selecting a `UL` with a class of `scenario` whereas you want the `LI`. Secondly `[id="scenario"]` should just be `#scenario`, and thirdly when dealing with IDs they should be unique, so you just want `$('#scenario')` - no tagnames necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul[id="scenario"] li').addClass("active");
```

can be

```
$('ul li#scenario').removeClass("disabled").addClass("active");
```

If a `li` has the disabled class it will be removed. If it doesn't then nothing happens.  In either case the 'active' class will be added.

Comment: The ul you are adding before that selector doesn't have an id=scenario. Your selector should actually be `$('ul li#scenario')`

Comment: My intent is to activate just one 'li' which has the id=scenario from the 'ul' list. how do i do that?

Comment: you might have to add the bootsrap CSS and jquery as an external link to the fiddle from this link: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: It is because your component is not yet in the DOM when you try to select anything inside of it.  You will have to wait till after your component has been added to the DOM itself before you can select any items that are being appended to the component in your functions.

Comment: Finally got your fiddle to work an example of what I just mentioned above: https://jsfiddle.net/r3g62zuz/1/

Comment: thank you! I realize that the component is not yet in the DOM. I intend to activate the 'scenario' pill from within the addMenuBar() function. Is there not way to build the html without using if...else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79265/discussion-between-galitskyd-and-rookie).

Comment: sure..thanksfor helping me out..i have joined the room

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping me out. Basically what i am trying to do is that when the user is in the first tab, the other 2 should be disabled unless he fills the form in tab 1 properly. After the form in first tab is validated, then i wish to activate the 2nd tab 'resolutions'

Answer (score 2):

Use [switchClass()](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/)

```
$('li.disabled').switchClass("disabled", "active");
```

If you are not using jQuery UI, you can do

```
$('li.disabled').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('disabled');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Only available in jQuery UI.

Comment: that wont work either, i have created a fiddle in my question

Comment: @Rookie, where is the fiddle?

Comment: @Rookie, that link is broken

Comment: its working now, just that the javascript is in the html so its throwing messages

Comment: @Rookie, whenever I click that link I get an empty fiddle. Can you make a normal fiddle without collaboration?

Comment: Try $('li.disabled') instead of $('ul[id="scenario"] li.disabled')